# PDO form only adds to primary key

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

I have a table called genre, it is a table for a music database. The table contains two columns, genre_id and genre_name. Genre_id is the primary key and it is set to auto increment. I created a form to add genres, like this:

```
<?php
  if ( empty( $_POST ) ) {
?>
<form name="newaddgenre" action="newaddgenre.php" method="POST">
  <label for 'genre'>Genre: </label>
  <input type="text" name="genre_name"/>
    <br/>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
} else {
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = 'mysql';
    $db = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=musicdb', $user, $pass);
    $form = $_POST;
    $genre_name = $form[ 'genre_name' ];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO genre (genre_name)
    VALUES (genre_name)";
    $query  = $db->prepare( $sql );
    $query->execute( array( ':genre_name'=>$genre_name) );
  print_r( $_POST );
}
?>
```

When I open this in my browser, the form appears and I can add a genre, however when I do select * from genre, the only thing being created is the genre_id. There is no genre_name in the table. What am I doing wrong?

Disclaimer: This is for a homework assignment and I do not have much experience at all with PHP so forgive me if there is something obviously wrong with this code.

Comment: What's the `genre_name` table definition? And you have no placeholders in your query. Please read lectures ince again.

Comment: replace `VALUES (genre_name)` with `VALUES (:genre_name)`. Note: it is now a `placeholder` in the query? Rather than the original column name? Have I mentioned that prefixing placeholders and variable names with something to ensure they don't match with `database objects`, can save hours of debugging?

Comment: It's crazy how one : can make or break something... Thank you very much, that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:genre_name` has no definition in your SQL-Statement. Try lit like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO genre (genre_name)
VALUES (:genre_name)";
$query  = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array( ':genre_name'=>$genre_name) );
```